# How to use OWN DB and the LOGIN ROLE CONTROL at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, role

I know the login control in .NET will automatically create database file in App Data folder.
But I would like to use an external database instead and want to use the membership & role function provided by .NET as well. What is the way to achieve that?

1. How to use the auto-created db but keep all other data in the same db?
2. How to external db and also pick the data need to used by the login role control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure both membership provider and role provider to use different database

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6e9y4s5t(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6e9y4s5t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

But you need first to configure your own database to store providrs data. This can be done using aspnet_regsql.exe tool

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229862(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229862%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yea. I saw Aspnet_regsql.exe posts during my surfing. But duno exactly how to open or use it?

Comment: Aspnet_regsql.exe is a console app you should run from command prompt and change current folder to c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4(your framework version)

Comment: I found a way to open Aspnet_regsql.exe in this post: 

http://mahedee.blogspot.com/2012/06/aspnet-membership-step-by-step.html

Thanks